# Update Angular model after setting input value with jQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, bind, directive

I have this simple scenario:

Input element which value is changed by jQuery's val() method.

I am trying to update the angular model with the value that jQuery set. I tried to write a simple directive, but it's not doing what I want.

Here's the directive:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.directive('testChange', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {        
        element.bind('change', function() {
            console.log('value changed');
        })
    }
})
```

this is the jQuery part:

```
$(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('input').val('xxx');
    })
})
```

and html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <input test-change ng-model="foo" />
        <span>{{foo}}</span>
    </div>
</div>

<button>clickme</button>
```

Here is the fiddle with my try:
http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/743/

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Mix AngularJS and jQuery, outside the directives, is often a bad idea. Is jQuery mandatory for what you want to do ?

Comment: Why don't you set the click event with angular to a function in the controller to change the value of the model?

Comment: @Blackhole, I am using jquery upload plugin that do its work and puts the path to uploaded file into the hidden input. All I need is to have access to that path in angular model. So I thought I'll set it as a value of hidden input and after it is changed update the angular model.

Comment: I do not see Jquery call in your fiddle... Can you check and point where you change value with JQ?

Comment: Your fiddle links to a Todo sample app, which doesn't relate to this question.

Comment: sorry, I updated the fiddle address.

Comment: Try adding something like this inside your click handler (along with the "value changed" console log):

    scope.foo = element.val();
    scope.$apply();

What you want to do is to propagate the change back into your Angular model.  Because this is initiated outside of an Angular callback, the "$apply()" call is what will tell Angular to recognize the change and update its models.

Answer (score 330, accepted):

ngModel listens for "input" event, so to "fix" your code you'd need to trigger that event after setting the value:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var input = $('input');
    input.val('xxx');
    input.trigger('input'); // Use for Chrome/Firefox/Edge
    input.trigger('change'); // Use for Chrome/Firefox/Edge + IE11
});
```

For the explanation of this particular behaviour check out this answer that I gave a while ago: "[How does AngularJS internally catch events like 'onclick', 'onchange'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739960/how-does-angularjs-internally-catch-events-like-onclick-onchange/15740287#15740287)"

---

But unfortunately, this is not the only problem you have. As pointed out with other post comments, your jQuery-centric approach is plain wrong. For more info take a look at this post: [How do I “think in AngularJS” if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)).

Comment: Cool! With one exception: why it doesn't work on hidden inputs? When I switch my input type to text, it works as expected.

Comment: This solved a major issue when using jquery calendar plugins.  By hacking the plugin to trigger('input') after input.val() the ng-change event fires after user selects calendar date.  Thanks!

Comment: Works perfect on hidden input:

   element.triggerHandler("change");

Comment: this does not work for me.

     $("#Distance").val(data);
     $("#Distance").trigger('input');

Comment: @StasSvishov Provide a plunker example, perhaps I can help.

Comment: If using for a checkbox (like `<input type="checkbox" ng-model="SomeServerGeneratedID">`), you can say `$scope["SomeServerGeneratedID"] = false` (or true) to control it.

Comment: Sometimes you just need to trigger 1 function from a jquery library, there is no error in this approach I think, no need to do fancy stuff with definitions & etc.

Comment: With Angular 1.4.3, `input` event doesn't work on IE including IE11.

[`input` event works only when `$sniff.hasEvent('input')` is true](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.3/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1094) but [`$sniff.hasEvent('input')` is false even on IE11!](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.3/src/ng/sniffer.js#L72)

We can use [`change` event](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.3/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1128) instead.

Comment: Wow quite neat , works for my autocomplete , which had lot of other issues  when using directive

Comment: Really a great solution. Thanks a lot @Stewie. You made my day. :)

Comment: @Karol : Alternative you can use `style="display:none"` instead of `type="hidden"`.

Comment: thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaank you. you are a heroooooooooo

Comment: @ShuheiKagawa THANK YOU SO MUCH

Answer (score 61):

Hope this is useful for someone.

I was unable to get the `jQuery('#myInputElement').trigger('input')` event to be picked up my angular app.

I was however, able to get `angular.element(jQuery('#myInputElement')).triggerHandler('input')` to be picked up.

Comment: please explain the solution dont just write code. i get angular is not $ is not a function

Comment: $ represents jQuery here. It is tagged in the question.

Comment: This worked for me too while $('myInputElement').trigger('input') was flaky. It seemed to randomly work sometimes but not others and I never could establish a pattern. This solution works every time.

Comment: Mine is worked with # prefix:
`angular.element($('#myInputElement')).triggerHandler('input')`

Comment: This triggerHandler worked for me also, I was dealing with textarea not input. Thanks

Comment: That's the only solution that worked for me within a bunch o accepted solutions! thanks

Comment: The model is changed, but I can catch event by using ng-change. What is the problem?  Here is my code:                                                          `<input class="textColor" id="color_{{itemId}}" type="text"
                                       name='color_{{itemId}}'
                                       ng-model="color"
                                       ng-change="optToPreviewText()"/>`

Comment: This helped me very much to make `bootstrap-datepicker` work with Angular. I described it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41815629/1813219

Comment: This worked for me. angular.element($('#server_name_dld')).triggerHandler('input');

Comment: I had to change the event name from 'input' to change: `angular.element(jQuery('#myElementId')).triggerHandler('change')`

Answer (score 30):

The accepted answer which was triggering `input` event with jQuery didn't work for me. Creating an event and dispatching with native JavaScript did the trick.

```
$("input")[0].dispatchEvent(new Event("input", { bubbles: true }));
```

Comment: This was the solution for me too. Using Angular 1.1.5, jQuery 2.2.4 and Jasmine 2.5.3.
Very, VERY weird that no other trigger mechanisms work.

Comment: I was looking for the native JS method for triggering form validation when setting an input in a script and this worked for me, thanks.

Comment: Works even with Angular 5, great!

Comment: Thank you. Especially helpful in webview.evaluatejavascript

Answer (score 22):

I don't think jQuery is required here.

You can use [$watch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch) and [ng-click](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClick) instead

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input test-change ng-model="foo" />
    <span>{{foo}}</span>

    <button ng-click=" foo= 'xxx' ">click me</button>
    <!-- this changes foo value, you can also call a function from your controller -->
  </div>
</div>
```

In your controller :

```
$scope.$watch('foo', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  console.log(newValue);
  console.log(oldValue);
});
```

Comment: Thank you Utopik, you're right, I shouldn't mix jquery with angular when there is a way how to do the job using angular.

Answer (score 18):

You have to use the following code in order to update the scope of the specific input model as follows

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    var newVal = $(this).data('val');
    $('select').val(newVal).change();

    var scope = angular.element($("select")).scope();
    scope.$apply(function(){
        scope.selectValue = newVal;
    });
});
```

Comment: `var scope = angular.element($("select")).scope();
    scope.$apply(function(){
        scope.selectValue = newVal;
    });`  that portion helped  me a lot. My issue was updating an angular model after a jquery ajax call in the success function. It was slow with $http because there was duplicate change event listener for the element that was doing something else so i merged it into jQuery.

Comment: The use of element.scope() is a bad idea, because it works only with logging enabled. If you on a production site you should disable logging on your config with `$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);` or `$logProvider.debugEnabled(false);` See https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/docs/guide/production for more info.

Comment: I tried this method for hidden variable and it worked.         
        var li_cuboid_id = $('#li_cuboid_id');
        li_cuboid_id.val(json.cuboidId).change();
    
        var scope = angular.element($("#li_cuboid_id")).scope();
        scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.cuboidId = json.cuboidId;
        }); 
the hidden variable is defined as:         <input id="li_cuboid_id" type=hidden ng-model="cuboidId">

Answer (score 7):

I made modifications on only controller initialization by adding listener on action button:

```
$(document).on('click', '#action-button', function () {
        $timeout(function () {
             angular.element($('#input')).triggerHandler('input');
        });
});
```

Other solutions did not work in my case.

Answer (score 4):

**I know it's a bit late to answer here but maybe I may save some once's day.**

I have been dealing with the same problem. A model will not populate once you update the value of input from jQuery. I tried using trigger events but no result.

Here is what I did that may save your day.

Declare a variable within your script tag in HTML.

Like:

```
<script>
 var inputValue="";

// update that variable using your jQuery function with appropriate value, you want...

</script>
```

Once you did that by using below service of angular.

> $window

Now below getData function called from the same controller scope will give you the value you want.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('imageManagerCtrl',['$scope','$window',function($scope,$window) {

$scope.getData = function () {
    console.log("Window value " + $window.inputValue);
}}]);
```

Answer (score 3):

I've written this little plugin for jQuery which will make all calls to `.val(value)` update the angular element if present:

```
(function($, ng) {
  'use strict';

  var $val = $.fn.val; // save original jQuery function

  // override jQuery function
  $.fn.val = function (value) {
    // if getter, just return original
    if (!arguments.length) {
      return $val.call(this);
    }

    // get result of original function
    var result = $val.call(this, value);

    // trigger angular input (this[0] is the DOM object)
    ng.element(this[0]).triggerHandler('input');

    // return the original result
    return result; 
  }
})(window.jQuery, window.angular);
```

Just pop this script in after jQuery and angular.js and `val(value)` updates should now play nice.

---

Minified version:

```
!function(n,t){"use strict";var r=n.fn.val;n.fn.val=function(n){if(!arguments.length)return r.call(this);var e=r.call(this,n);return t.element(this[0]).triggerHandler("input"),e}}(window.jQuery,window.angular);
```

---

Example:

```js
// the function
(function($, ng) {
  'use strict';
  
  var $val = $.fn.val;
  
  $.fn.val = function (value) {
    if (!arguments.length) {
      return $val.call(this);
    }
    
    var result = $val.call(this, value);
    
    ng.element(this[0]).triggerHandler('input');
    
    return result;
    
  }
})(window.jQuery, window.angular);

(function(ng){ 
  ng.module('example', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {
      $scope.output = "output";
      
      $scope.change = function() {
        $scope.output = "" + $scope.input;
      }
    });
})(window.angular);

(function($){  
  $(function() {
    var button = $('#button');
  
    if (button.length)
      console.log('hello, button');
    
    button.click(function() {
      var input = $('#input');
      
      var value = parseInt(input.val());
      value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
      
      input.val(value + 1);
    });
  });
})(window.jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="example" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <input type="number" id="input" ng-model="input" ng-change="change()" />
  <span>{{output}}</span>
  <button id="button">+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry to grave dig this up, but any idea how this would/could work with checkbox or selects since those use .prop instead of .val? This is working perfectly for input .val changes at the very least so thank you!

Comment: @Austin I'm afraid I don't know. This is a 5 year old question about two technologies that are widely considered outdated, as such I haven't kept the knowledge in my head. Best of luck getting the solution you need though.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using IE, you have to use: input.trigger("change");

Answer (score 2):

add `.change()` after setting the value.

example:`('id').val.('value').change();`

also don't forget to add `onchange` or `ng-change` tag in html

Answer (score 0):

I did this to be able to update the value of ngModel from the outside with Vanilla/jQuery:

```js
function getScope(fieldElement) {
    var $scope = angular.element(fieldElement).scope();
    var nameScope;
    var name = fieldElement.getAttribute('name');
    if($scope) {
        if($scope.form) {
            nameScope = $scope.form[name];
        } else if($scope[name]) {
            nameScope = $scope[name];
        }
    }
    return nameScope;
}

function setScopeValue(fieldElement, newValue) {
    var $scope = getScope(fieldElement);
    if($scope) {
        $scope.$setViewValue(newValue);
        $scope.$validate();
        $scope.$render();
    }
}

setScopeValue(document.getElementById("fieldId"), "new value");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not what OP asked, but for any soul that might be as well writing an **userscript** that goes through input fields and fills the required details. Nothing (fully) worked for me, but finally managed to get it done this way:

```
var el = $('#sp_formfield_fw_ip');
el.val("some value");
angular.element(el).triggerHandler('focus');
angular.element(el).triggerHandler('input');
angular.element(el).triggerHandler('change');
angular.element(el).triggerHandler('blur');
```

Open developer tools, and inspect `input` field for added events. There I found all of them (in my case): `focus`, `input`, `change` and `blur`.