# Angular data-binding after setting input value with karma

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, karma-runner

My question is extremely close to that one :

[Update Angular model after setting input value with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109850/update-angular-model-after-setting-input-value-with-jquery)

But, here, my input is modified by  the val() method of Karma runner :

```
element('#stuff_input').val('theNewValForStuff');
```

I won't detail my test here, it would be irrelevant. But you will easily guess that the test will fail if binding is not properly maintained.

In production, #stuff_input is actually modified with the keyboard by user, never with any jQuery method of course. So I don't want to use $watch, I don't want to introduce any more complexity into my production code just because :

1) Karma do not allow keyboard input natively

2) Karma event do not maintain data-binding with val()

Any idea of how to solve this ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean `angular.element('#stuff_input').val(...)`?

Comment: No, it is within karma test, so i'm reaching the element directly with element(...)

Comment: Oh, I see, you mean ngScenario's `element` function. Have you tried `input(model_name).enter(value)`?

Comment: Michaeal Benford has the above correct answer : input(model_name).enter(value). I feel it more like a hackn but it work so I would have tick it as the correct answer if I could.