# Angular forms are not detecting browser-inserted text

Tags: javascript, angularjs

*Note that in the image below the fields with a yellow background were auto-filled by Chrome (or maybe by Lastpass)*

I have a login widget that I've created in Angular, and it works great.  One problem that I've had though, is that if I define the email text field like:

```
<input type="email" ng-model='user.email' name="email" required>
```

I will get a form.email.$error.required error if I submit with a browser inserted value as shown below.  Also, the user object will not have a value for email unless i modify that defaulted text.

I can manually search the DOM for the value of that input, but that's not a very Angular way to solve this issue.  My other option is to create my own input directive that initializes the input by checking if there is a value on the DOM.  But I'm wondering if there is a quicker workaround.

[image: Login Widget]

Comment: What do you mean with "browser inserted value"?

Comment: @MikeRobinson I think the OP means the autocomplete feature of the browser.

Comment: That's because angular model is updated only on "input" event and when browser's autocomplete script fills out the fields, this event is not fired. Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17110709/1095616. Basically you should be able to handle this by applying custom directive to each of your fields and triggering `input` event inside $timeout.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11710295/896341

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm not understanding your problem, but isn't this just a matter of using $scope.$apply(), first thing in your submit function?

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-$scope.$apply()