# Changing an Angular ng-model with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-chrome

I'm writing a Google Chrome extension which will interact directly with an AngularJS app.

Data is passed into Chrome's localstorage (`chrome.storage.local`) in one page, and then retrieved when the user loads my app's page.

The Angular is basically just a form with `ng-models` attached, like so:

```
 <input id="q1" ng-model="inputName" >
 <input id="q2" ng-model="inputTitle" >
 <input id="q3" ng-model="inputAge" >

 <button ng-click='submit()' >
```

The `submit()` function saves the `ng-model` values to my database to be retrieved later.

There are similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109850/update-angular-model-after-setting-input-value-with-jquery) which use older versions of AngularJS and I cannot get to work with Angular 1.2+ (I'm on Angular 1.2.2).

I've tried:

```
$('#q1').val(obj.title).trigger('input');
```

I've also tried:

```
$('#q1').val(obj.title);
angular.element($('#q1')).triggerHandler('input');
```

Neither work, in fact the latter makes no value change occur at all. What's the fix?

**EDIT**: Here's the Angular function being called on click, if there's something I can do in here to force `ng-model` to check the html input's value (that was set by jQuery in the Google Chrome extension) then that could be a solution:

```
 $scope.submit = function(){

        var theEvent = {
            inputTitle: $scope.inputTitle,
            inputName: $scope.inputName,
            inputAge: $scope.inputAge
        };

        $rootScope.existing = theEvent;

        $http({
            url: '/api/saveToMongo/newEvent',
            method: "POST",
            data: theEvent
        }).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            $cookies.oldSession = data;

            $location.path('/collect');
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          console.log("There was an error submitting!");
        });

    };
```

All of these are returning `null` when I submit to my database, although if I type in the values manually then they work fine.

Comment: Does ng-click(submit()) really work ? I mean, instead of ng-click="submit()" ?

Comment: I really would see the full angular controller : you are trying to change HTML element value, when you should change (e.g.) $scope property value.

Comment: @enguerranws Apologies, that's an error in my questions, will update.

Will chuck in the `$scope.submit()` function, but as mentioned above I'm trying to change the `input`'s value via jQuery (which is being called from within a Google Chrome extension), which I in turn want to force the `ng-model` to update.

Comment: I really just want to be able to tell Angular (probably within `$scope.submit()` to check the value of the html `inputs` and update the `ng-models`...

Comment: can't you re-set $scope.inputTitle (etc.) in $http.success() ? e.g. $scope.inputTitle = data.newVal ?

Comment: `.trigger('input')` should work fine in Angular 1.2.2: http://plnkr.co/edit/tQea2bBTaOl4f552LDfU?p=preview

Comment: try: angular.element(document.querySelector("input")).triggerHandler("click");