# Ambiguity in installing Angularjs datepicker

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I read the Documentation of this Angularjs datepicker on Github http://dalelotts.github.io/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/
and I find difficulty understanding :

- dependecies
- dding the model since I already have a model

and finally how I call it from a text box field.

Comment: Dependencies are on the github page https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker

Comment: I did not understand dependency itself.