# Set value of multiple dropdowns

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to set the value of many `select` elements when a user presses a button.

I have tried the jQuery way:

```
    vm.passAllInspections = function ($event) {
    $(".tbl-inspections option[value=pass]").attr("selected", "selected");
        console.log($event);
    }
```

This works but does not update ng-model or even make it fire. I looked at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109850/update-angular-model-after-setting-input-value-with-jquery/17110709#17110709) which gives details on the `input` element. I could not get the trigger event to happen?

```
$('button').click(function(){
var input = $('input');
input.val('xxx');
input.trigger('input');
});
```

So then I tried to use the `$compile` directive `$compile(vm)($scope);` that doesn't work as I wasn't sure if it had to be the exact ng-model property?

Then I was looking at useing `ng-click="vm.eicr.inspections='pass'"` but wasn't sure how to apply it to every ng-model property.

How can I press a button and add `pass` to a list of dropdowns and fire the `ng-model` so the properties are all set.

Comment: so, just to be sure: you got, for example, 3 listboxes. You click a button and want the `ng-model` of all 3 listboxes to be set to a certain value, right?

Comment: yes i want the model to update as well

Answer (score 1):

You have your listbox:

```
<select data-ng-model="myValue">
   <option value="1">value 1 </option>
   <option value="2">value 2 </option>
   <option value="3">value 3 </option>
</select>
```

You have a button:

```
<button data-ng-click="setListboxToValue('2')" value="Click me!"/>
```

When you click the button, you trigger this function:

```
$scope.setListboxToValue = function(value) {

   $scope.myValue = value;
}
```

This will set your listbox to the value you want.

Full example code: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k5wsLorf/3/)

Comment: thanks for your help, I wanted it to go over many there must be 30 select's,  and update each model property.

Comment: @StudentRik can you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with some example code?