# On values from script function to input field ng-model gives undefined Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using google maps in my application in which i use maps related code in script tag and on after the search result it gives longitude, latitude and i am getting these values and showing these values in input

here is my part of script code which passes lon and lat to input

```
 document.getElementById('lat').value = place.geometry.location.lat();

    document.getElementById('lng').value = place.geometry.location.lng();
```

here is my HTML code

```
<div class="from-group">
<li>Latitude: <input class="from-control" ng-model="formData.lat" id="lat"></li>
<li>Longitude: <input class="from-control" ng-model="formData.lng" id="lng" ></li>
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="values()" id="idbtn" >Results</button>
</div>
```

but it gives undefined for ng-model="formData.lng" and when i enter some thing 
manually it works fine but when values comes from script it gives undefined

here is my controller code

```
Sscope.formData={}; 
    $scope.values = function () {

    console.log($scope.formData.lat);
    console.log($scope.formData.lng);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass the lat and long from your javascript file with

```
document.getElementById('lat').value = place.geometry.location.lat();
document.getElementById('lng').value = place.geometry.location.lng();
```

The ng-model is not getting updated or 'triggered'

try

```
angular.element($('#myInputElement')).triggerHandler('input')
```

there is a good post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109850/update-angular-model-after-setting-input-value-with-jquery) that may help.

You may consider using a google maps directive such as [ng-map](http://ngmap.github.io/)

Comment: no idea how to use this approach but i use other way $scope.$watch but its not working need bit more explaination thanx

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `$scope` variable with `$apply`.

```
var latElem = angular.element(document.getElementById('lat'))
var latScope = latElem.scope();
latScope.$apply("formData.lat=" + place.geometry.location.lat());
```

`$apply` evaluates an Angular Expression and initiates an AngularJS digest cycle to update the framework.