# Angular ng-model not updating when checkbox checked with jquery property

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox, angular-ngmodel

The code is trying to set a checked property through jquery .prop function.
But ng-model is still blank.

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $("#mybutton").on('click',function(){
        $("#mycheckbox").prop('checked',true);
    });
});
```

```
<input type="button" id="mybutton" value="click">
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" name="one" ng-model="arr[1]" value="1" />

{{arr}}   -- is blank when checked with jquery and not blank when manually checked.
```

When i manually check the checkbox then ng-model is binded and its value is set.
Can you please help how to update ng-model when checkbox is checked with jQuery.

Comment: Have you tried using `ng-checked="arr[1]"` instead? Is `arr` in your scope?

Comment: Duplicated question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109850/update-angular-model-after-setting-input-value-with-jquery

Comment: @A.Gille  Yes, the model gets set when i manually set it. but when it is triggered though a button click then it does not get set. i.e when checkbox is checked through a button click

Comment: Like Gabe's post above, can you try triggering the input event.  I doubt what you are doing will work, unless you have some Angular way in it.

Answer (score 0):

You should read, when angular rechecks binded property like ng model and [when digest runs](https://www.ng-book.com/p/The-Digest-Loop-and-apply/).

Wrap your function with $scope.$applyAsync() method like this:

```
   $scope.$applyAsync($("#mycheckbox").prop('checked',true));
```

this should be done inside the controller.

If you want no do in scopeless path you can use $timeout.

And once more. All dom manipulation should be done inside directives/components where you can access variuos angular tools like applyAsync and others.