# bootstrap-datepicker does not update AngularJS model when picking date

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using AngularJS with [this bootstrap-datepicker plugin](https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=4&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox):

> Datepicker for Bootstrap v1.6.4 (https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker)
>
> Copyright 2012 Stefan Petre
>
> Improvements by Andrew Rowls

I have it bound like this:

```
<input type="text" data-provide="datepicker" ng-model="obj.FirstDate" />
```

I get the values to inputs using `ng-model`.

When I type the date into this field using keyboard it all works OK, but when I click on a field and select a date from the Datepicker:

- the model doesn't get updated,
- the field is not treated as dirty (no `ng-dirty` class).

Is there a way to tell Angular to update value of `obj.FirstDate` when using the Datepicker? For example to attach it to an event? Or any other way that this would work?

I have a few of these fields so I don't want to write the script which attaches to a field using its `id`. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much time of struggling with this I was forced to use below code to fix every of my datepicker instances at once:

```
function fixDatepickerTriggerChange() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[data-provide="datepicker"]').datepicker().on('changeDate', function (e) {
            angular.element($(this)).triggerHandler('input');
        });
    });
}
```

And run it from within the `angular.controller`.

Based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23850753/1813219.