# How to imitate keypress event for angularJS input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, events

SOLVED: [Update Angular model after setting input value with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109850/update-angular-model-after-setting-input-value-with-jquery)

Here's code with `<input>` element. It runs with AngularJS.
I need to imitate keypress for it.
If I use $().val() or [autotype](https://github.com/mmonteleone/jquery.autotype) library, which imitates keypress events, AngularJS script don't handle it. I can't press "Create group" button.
But If I type manually, button works.

```
<div class="md_simple_modal_body">    
    <form class="modal_simple_form ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-submit="updateGroup()">   
      <h4 my-i18n="group_create_modal_title">Create group</h4>    
      <div class="md-input-group md-input-animated" my-labeled-input="">
        <label class="md-input-label" my-i18n="group_create_name">Group name</label>
        <input class="md-input ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched" type="text" ng-model="group.name" my-focused="">
      </div>    
    </form>    
  </div>    
  <div class="md_simple_modal_footer">
    <button class="btn btn-md" ng-click="$dismiss()" my-i18n="modal_cancel">Cancel</button>
    <button class="btn btn-md btn-md-primary" ng-class="{disabled: group.creating}" ng-click="createGroup()" ng-bind="group.creating ? 'group_create_submit_active' : 'group_create_submit' | i18n" ng-disabled="group.creating">Create group</button>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Function in controller:

```
$scope.createGroup = function () {
  if (!$scope.group.name) {
    return
  }
  $scope.group.creating = true
  var inputUsers = []
  angular.forEach($scope.userIDs, function (userID) {
    inputUsers.push(AppUsersManager.getUserInput(userID))
  })
  return MtpApiManager.invokeApi('messages.createChat', {
    title: $scope.group.name,
    users: inputUsers
  }).then(function (updates) {
    ApiUpdatesManager.processUpdateMessage(updates)

    if (updates.updates && updates.updates.length) {
      for (var i = 0, len = updates.updates.length, update; i < len; i++) {
        update = updates.updates[i]
        if (update._ == 'updateNewMessage') {
          $rootScope.$broadcast('history_focus', {peerString: AppChatsManager.getChatString(update.message.to_id.chat_id)
          })
          break
        }
      }
      $modalInstance.close()
    }
  })['finally'](function () {
    delete $scope.group.creating
  })
}
```

I tried:

```
$("form[ng-submit='updateGroup()']").find("input[ng-model='group.name']").val("12223");
```

And

```
$("form[ng-submit='updateGroup()']").find("input[ng-model='group.name']").autotype("12223"); // With library. Link poster earlier.
```

Comment: One more person to use both Angular and jQuery together (sigh). People, please _stop_ using these two at the same time. So many problems, like this one, come directly from the fact that you are trying to make two very different things work together. Remove jQuery, or remove Angular, and you'll see, many problems will go away.

Comment: It isn't my code, so I don't have a choice :)

Comment: So you guys load two very different libraries and try to mix them up, leading to this kind of problem and adding complexity, and apparently there is no way to do otherwise and write a clean app? That's unfortunate :/ Good luck then, I guess

Comment: Angular uses Jquery internally. One should try not to make use of JQuery within an Angular app, but the idea that they should be entirely mutually exclusive things is a misnomer.

Comment: Please add the JavaScript code that you've tried.

Comment: What is `group.creating`? Show a bit of controller's code.

Comment: SOLVED with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109850/update-angular-model-after-setting-input-value-with-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer in another question:
[Update Angular model after setting input value with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109850/update-angular-model-after-setting-input-value-with-jquery)
Just need to use `$(element).trigger('input');` after changing input value with jQuery.