# Update Angular 8 model after setting input value with jQuery

Tags: jquery, angular, single-page-application

I want to update Angular model when the value is cleared in JQuery.

My Angular version is 8.

Although I referred to the following article, it did not work.

[Update Angular model after setting input value with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109850/update-angular-model-after-setting-input-value-with-jquery)

HTML Part

```
<input id="name" type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" />
```

JQuery Part

```
$('#name').val('');
$('#name').trigger('input');
```

Comment: Why do you want to use jQuery when you can do it with Angular?

Comment: instead of jquery just use `this.name=''` on place of `$('#name').val('');`

Comment: @HarunYilmaz Thanks for your comment
There are various circumstances and it is absolutely necessary to do so.