# AngularJS : Pass results from datepicker to ng-model

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datetimepicker, angular-ngmodel

I have a datetimepicker, I'm needing this to pass the date inside the text to the model.

I would place this in a fiddle but i don't know how as it has the bootstrap timepicker located here `http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker` angular(obvs) and other stuff

This is what i have so far;

```
  <div class="form-group">
                  <div class='input-group date' ng-model="package.timeA">
                      <input type='text' id='datetimepicker3' ng-model="package.timeA" ng-change="alert('Hello')" class="form-control" />
                      <span class="input-group-addon" ng-model="package.timeA">
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                      </span>
                  </div>
              </div>

          <script type="text/javascript">
              $(function () {
                  $('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
                      format: 'LT'
                  }).on("dp.change", function(e) {
                    document.getElementById('datetimepicker3').value = e.date;
                  });
              });
          </script>
```

The datetimepicker needs to pass into the model, Totally stuck until it does so i can submit it to the DB

Any Ideas?>

Comment: This needs to be in a directive. There you can update scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to trigger the "input" event of `#datetimepicker3` since ng-model listens for this event hence it shall update its value :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
              $(function () {
                  $('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
                      format: 'LT'
                  }).on("dp.change", function(e) {
                    document.getElementById('datetimepicker3').value = e.date;
                    $('#datetimepicker3').trigger('input'); // trigger input event
                  });
              });
          </script>
```

As per [How does AngularJS internally catch events like 'onclick', 'onchange'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739960/how-does-angularjs-internally-catch-events-like-onclick-onchange/15740287#15740287)

Angular, by default, listens for `input` event, and, in case it's not supported by the browser, it will fall back to `keydown` + `change` events.

Events are binded with jQlite's bind method (unless you also have a full jQuery included, in which case its bind method will take over).

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class='input-group date'>
   <input type='text' id='datetimepicker3' 
     ng-model="package.timeA" 
     ng-change="alert('Hello')" 
     class="form-control" />
   <span class="input-group-addon" ng-model="package.timeA">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
   </span>
</div>
```

this code is enough to pass the value to the model on the scope

```
ng-model="package.timeA"
```

No more code is needed to understand how datepicker works with bootstrap [see this article](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1198/angularjs-bootstrap-datepicker-enable-disable-dates-with-configuration-exapmle)